# Use string variable to access value of object

Tags: javascript, variables, object, selector, javascript-objects

I have a text input.

I want the user to be able to fill out a value in that text input like some of these examples:

- `results[0].address_components[0].long_name`
- `results[0].formatted_address`
- `fo.o[0].bar` (where `fo.o` is a single key)
- etc. (pretty much literally anything)

Then I want to take that value and use it as a key on some parsed JSON. So like...

`$.parseJSON('data.json').results[0].address_components[0].long_name` would return something like `San Francisco`.

How can I do this?

If I save the input value as a variable, say `selector`, and then try `$.parseJSON('data.json')[selector]` it just comes back undefined.

If I try to regex the selector and convert all instances of `[` into `.` and remove all `]` and split at `.` then reduce, then selectors like `fo.o` (one key) will break...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You should generally set the results of parseJSON to a variable, rather than parse it every time you access it.  parseJSON is generally going to go down to C code (depending on the environment), but it will still be really inefficient to call it over and over.

```
var res = $.parseJSON('data.json');
```

From there, you can access it like you would any other JavaScript object:

`res.results`, which is identical to `res["results"]` (which, in your case appears to be some kind of array).

A string key with special characters (`.`, `-`, and pretty much anything non a-zA-Z0-9) is always accessed via the second form:  `res["fo.o"]`.

Note that this chains, so you can access `res["fo.o"]["bar"]` exactly as you'd address `res["fo.o"].bar`.

Comment: Yeah I am assigning it to a var. I think I just posted it like that as an example.

Thanks for the heads up about `res["fo.o"]["bar"]` working. I can probably iterate and figure it out now. =)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using a JavaScript library like [lodash](https://lodash.com/) for this (if this is feasible in your project, otherwise looking at its implementation might help):

It provides a large set of utility functions. The [`get`](http://devdocs.io/lodash/index#get) function does exactly what you are looking for, namely it resolves a path on an object.

Sample code (assuming `_` is your `lodash` reference):

```
var path = 'results[0].address_components[0].long_name'; // the user input
var data = $.parse('data.json');
var result = _.get(data, path); // resolves the path on the data object
```

As for the `fo.o` property name, I doubt there would be an easy solution, as this essentially makes your syntax ambiguous. How would you distinguish between a property `fo.o` and `fo`?

Comment: I suppose the trick would be to wrap `fo.o` in double quotes or something. I'll check into lodash, thanks! =)

Comment: That's what I was thinking too... I don't think lodash could handle that though and you'd probably have to split up the entered path in your own code first before calling the lodash `get` function.

Comment: Well, I've got the regex now to convert `results[0].address_components[0].long_name` to `["results"][0]["address_components"][0]["long_name"]` but now I don't know how to combine that string with my parsed JSON...

Everything I try just concatenates them together into `[object Object]["results"][0]["address_components"][0]["long_name"]`.

`console.log(parsedJSON["results"][0]["address_components"][0]["long_name"])` does work though.

Comment: To use lodash's `get` function, you should be able to use your original user input (as in your question, e.g. `results[0].address_components[0].long_name`) as the second parameter. The first parameter would be the object you obtain from `$.parseJSON('data.json')`. The only case you'd have to handle separately, would be the properties that contain special character such as the `.`.

Answer (score 0):

use **eval**. You would put everything as a string. So just concatenate strings based on the input. Then eval it. for example:

```
var str = "$.parseJSON('data.json').results[0].address_components[0].long_name";
```

and then eval it at runtime.

```
var result = eval(str);
```

Comment: Isn't there some holy rule about not combining user input and eval?

Comment: well it seems like a programmer tool anyway. whatever works.